# Groovy has a size property for Collection?

Tags: collections, groovy

I have written a piece of code where I'm checking the size of an ArrayList like:

```
[1,2,3].size
```

All works well on Groovy Console and with Grails embedded Tomcat server. But once I deployed this code to Websphere Application Server, I receivec an exception stating

```
Exception evaluating property 'size' for java.util.ArrayList, Reason: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: size for class: java.lang.Integer.
```

After a while of debugging, testing and plenty of WTFs, I realized that there were parenthesis missing from the method call. The property notation should not work as there's no method `getSize()` for Collection (it's plain `size()`) and this all makes sense.

What's puzzling me, is **why does `someCollection.size` work on Groovy Console and Grails?**

Grails and Groovy Console version is 2.3.6

Comment: Do versions of groovy used differ?

Comment: `ArrayList` has a private var `size` (at least in sun jdk 1.7u67).  I would expect different JDKs.

Comment: The Grails framework is bundled within the app, so that's same for both. Different JDKs is very good possible candidate. Websphere probably has it's own implementation.

Comment: Can you find out which one and disasm it?  Are you using sun/openjdk, where it works?

Comment: My laptop: **Groovy Version: 2.3.6 JVM: 1.6.0_45 Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc. OS: Windows 7** ... and I'll have to get back on the Websphere JDK version tomorrow.

Comment: The server version is probably: **java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pap6460sr12-20121025_01(SR12))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 AIX ppc64-64 jvmap6460sr12-20121024_126067 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20121024_126067
JIT  - r9_20120914_26057
GC   - 20120928_AA)
JCL  - 20121014_01** I'll have to skip the disasm, at least for the time being.

Comment: ... and downloading needs a login and i guess there is no public repo for J9 around?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ArrayList` in (at least) the Sun JDK 1.7u67 and in [OpenJDK 1.6](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/cdb085a5127c/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java) holds a `private int size`, which is accessible to groovy.  If your other environment uses another JDK, this var might not exist and groovy would fallback to the interpretation of `[1,2,3]*.getSize()`, which then fails.

Comment: The implementation of ArrayList, where the code in question does not work indeed has no size member variable.

Comment: If the list is empty, the interpretation `*.getSize()` will not fail and will return an empty list. So `[].size == []`, very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

On Groovy version: `2.4.21`, (Jenkins: `2.387.2`), we can use the `size()` method.

Adding as, `getSize()`, did not work for me. Error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.getSize() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: size(), size(), size(), get(int), get(int), getAt(int)
```