# How can shorten this logic

Tags: java, if-statement, design-patterns, groovy, coding-style

Consider below JSON:

```
"collection1" :
{
    "list1" : ["val1","val2","val3"]
    "list2" : ["val1","val2","val3"] 
},
"collection2" :
{
    "list1" : ["val1","val2","val3"]
    "list2" : ["val1","val2","val3"] 
},
```

I want to return true if there is no value for both `collection1` and `collection2`. Now whether there is "no value" can be determined by many ways:

- **both** `collection1` **and** `collection2` are `null`
- **all** `collection1`, `collection2.list1` **and** `collection2.list2` are `null`
- `collection1` is `null` **and**

  - `collection2.list1` **and** `collection2.list2`  contains no elements **or**
  - `collection2.list1` is `null` **and**  `collection2.list2` contains no elements **or**
  - `collection2.list2` is `null` **and**  `collection2.list1` contains no elements

You can realise this can lead to many combinations. I can obiviously translate this directly to `if-else` blocks, but am finding it boring, or may be I am just bored, my head isnt working and really need some coffee because I am not able to guess anything simpler, **smaller (possibly few liner if one liner is not possible) and concise** on such a simple/dull thing. Or am I just wasting my time and over thinking? Ans simply convert that to `if-else` block and leave?

I am writing code in groovy, so Java solution will also work.

Comment: Does `boolean value = json.collection1 && json.collection2` get you close?

Comment: what it is supposed to evaluate? Is it similar to `json.collection1 == null && json.collection2 == null`?

Comment: @Mahesha999 Why is the data model so flexible? That seems to be your problem in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is the expression you're looking for:

```
!json?.collection1 && !json?.collection2?.list1?.size() && !json?.collection2?.list2?.size()
```

**Explanation:**

`!json?.collection1` it's only true if `json.collection1` is `null`

`!json?.collection2?.list1?.size()` it's only true if `collection2` is null or `collection2.list1` is null or empty.

`!json?.collection2?.list2?.size()` it's only true if `collection2` is null or `collection2.list2` is null or empty.

Here [`?` safe navigation operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_safe_navigation_operator) helps.

Hope it helps,

Comment: thats why I started loving Groovy lately :'p  I dont know if it is correct or not in view of programming language design, but I am liking the way groovy-makers have constructed operators for frequent functions that we need to perform. The other one I like is [`==~`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_match_operator)

Comment: please note that, `size` is an implementation detail of the oracle/open jdk.  the correct method call here is `size()`.  see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26533211/3181392 . also an empty list is "falsey" in groovy terms. `assert ![]==true`

Comment: @albcif are there more such groovy operators?

Answer (score 0):

```
(collection1 == null) && 
((collection2 == null) || (nullOrEmpty(collection2.list1) && nullOrEmpty(collection2.list2)))
```

using a helper function (which also could be inlined)

```
boolean nullOrEmpty(list) { return list == null || list.empty(); }
```