# Groovy code fail when debugging in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, groovy, size, parentheses

When I'm trying to run my Groovy code in IntelliJ IDEA it fails on using **.size** without parenthesis:

```
response.errors.size == 0
```

although there is no error in the response ('errors' array is empty).

```
Assertion failed: 

assert response.errors.size == 0
       |        |      |
       |        null   []
       |
       common.RESTResponse@53abfc07
```

I have to use **.size()** then everything is working OK.

```
response.errors.size() == 0
```

> Groovy Version: 4.0.0 JVM: 17.0.8 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac
> OS X
>
> IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.2 (Ultimate Edition)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is `errors`? This could be the same problem like this (IDEA might use a different JDK to run the tests): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26532434/groovy-has-a-size-property-for-collection

Comment: If there is no error, then `errors` is not present in the response at all.

Comment: according to the assertion message the `response.errors` returns null - so, any accessor after will throw an error. if `errors` returns a list then you should use `size()` to determine size. also if it's a list you could simplify the assertion: `assert !response.errors`